# Internal links doesn't work from same page as anchors, but from other pages - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I got an issue with internal links on this test website: http://www.bedbreakfastsoenderborg.dk/test

It consists of two pages (home-page and a contact page). I got 4 menu links in total - 3 of which are pointing to anchors on the home-page.

I've marked the anchors as follows: `<div id="faciliteter"> </div>`

The internal links are made like: `<a href="http://bedbreakfastsoenderborg.dk/test/#faciliteter">Faciliteter / Værelser</a>`

**The problem:**

If I from the home-page click on any of the three anchor links, I'm not getting directed to the anchors on the same page. Nothing happens.

If I'm on the contact page and I click one of the anchor links pointing to a section on the home-page, I'm getting directed perfectly fine.

After many failed attempts at finding a solution, I hoped one of you might be able to spot something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: the prbolem is with your js file from theme: `http://bedbreakfastsoenderborg.dk/test/wp-content/themes/aspire-pro/js/jquery.localScroll.min.js?ver=1.2.8b`. its binding all click events for `a` tags. you can add some other js script for undinding events, modifye exists one

Comment: Thanks for helping Samvel! I'll get someone to look at that file and see if it'll sort my issues out :-)